# After authorization user has not username and roles

Tags: php, symfony

I've two user providers, one of which in_memory.

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, iac_provider]
    iac_provider:
        entity:
            class: IACOvirugBundle:User
            property: username

    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                external_service:  { password: AG4QIf4, roles: 'ROLE_EXTERNAL_API' }
```

and access_control

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/external/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/soap-service, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/service/check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/external, roles: ROLE_EXTERNAL_API }
    - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

After authorization by user from memory, i've Access denied.
And i see in profiler:

[image]

And i see into log

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can we see your role_hierarchy ? (security.yml)

Comment: `    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_EXTERNAL_API: ROLE_USER
`